# Manually close connection in request stream HTTP.jl

Tags: http, julia

My problem is the following. I am making a GET request which returns a stream and after some time I get my desired data but the webserver does not close the connection so I want to close it on my side. My code is as follows:

```
using HTTP

HTTP.open(:GET, "https://someurl.com", query=Dict(
    "somekey"=>"somevalue"
)) do io
    for i = 1:4
        println("DATA: ---")
        @show io
        println(String(readavailable(io)))
    end
    @info "Close read"
    closeread(io)
    @info "After close read"
    @show io
end
println("At the end!")
```

However I never reach the last line. I have tried dozens of different approaches by consulting the docs of `HTTP.jl`, but none worked for me and I suspect that is, because this webserver is not sending the `Close: Connection`, but I have not been able to find an example that closes the connection on the client side manually / forcefully.

Interesting note: When running this from the REPL and closing the connection via hitting Ctrl-C a couple of times and then rerunning the script it hangs forever. I have to wait some random amount of seconds to minutes then before I can run it again "successfully". I suspect this has to do with the stale connection not being closed properly.

As is evident I am neither very proficient in networks programming nor julia, so any help would be highly appreciated!

EDIT: I suspect I was not quite clear enough on the behaviour of the webserver and what I wanna do so I will try to break it down as simple as possible: I want to get responses from the webserver until I detect a certain keyword. After that I wanna close the connection - the webserver would keep on sending me data but I already got all I am interested in so I don't want to wait for another few minutes for the webserver to close the connection for me!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is assuming the 4 times you will get the data by calling `readavailable` which might not be true depending on the buffer state,

Rather than that your loop should be:

```
while !eof(io)
    println("DATA: ---")
    println(String(readavailable(io)))
end
```

In your case the connection gets stacked because you try to read four chunks of data and perhaps you are getting everything in the first chunk and than the connection blocks.

On top of that, if your a using the `do` syntax you should not close the resource yourself - it will be done automatically at the end of the block.

Comment: This doesn‘t work since eof never becomes true (in my testing). Tried this already and waited for 3 minutes ... You got a fair point with the 4 thing, however I know for this particular webserver that I get endless responses as stated in my question (I mean sure there will be some timeout (>= 3mins) server side). In my future code I would have a while loop waiting for a certain keyword to appear.

Comment: I added an edit to the original question to better explain my desired behaviour :)

Comment: If this server is non standard perhaps you could try to open a direct socket connection with `HTTP.openraw` which gives o broader control on what is going on. Moreover I do not like `readavailable` being combined with reading an endless data stream - again this should be then processed using some lower level API.

Comment: Thank for the tip. That sounds a bit too complicated for me, I have rewritten the script in python and there it is as easy as iterating over `iter_lines()` and just `break` when I got what I need. I will be sure to give Julia another try some time soon.